# Prove that if $Y$ is a random discrete variable with $P(Y\geq 0)=1$ then if $a>0$ is some constant, $E(Y)\geq aP(Y\geq a)$

Tags: statistics

> Prove that if $Y$ is a random discrete variable with $P(Y\geq 0)=1$ then if $a>0$ is some constant, $E(Y)\geq aP(Y\geq a)$

So I know $E(Y)=\sum_y yp_y(y)$

And then I broke the sum into the terms greater then and less then $a$.

$$=\sum_{y\geq a} yp_Y(y) +\sum_{Y<a}yp_Y(y)$$
$$\geq \sum_{y\geq a} y p_Y(y)$$
$$\geq\sum_{y\geq a} ap_Y(y)=aP(Y\geq a)$$
Since $y\geq a$

I haven't used the fact that $P(Y\geq 0)=1$ though. So I think there must be a mistake in this or I've missed where I needed to use that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *did* use $\mathbb{P}(Y\geq 0)=1$ in your proof because

$$
\sum_{y\geq a} y\mathbb{P}(Y=y)+\sum_{y< a} y\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\geq \sum_{y\geq a} y\mathbb{P}(Y=y)
$$
is only true if $\sum_{y< a} y\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\geq 0$ which isn't a priori true if the sum contains negative terms.

You are, however, correct that the Markov inequality is true for a given $a$ as soon as $\mathbb{E} 1_{Y< a} Y\geq 0$ (and if this is true for every $a$, then necessarily, $Y$ must be positive).

Comment: Oh right thanks.I forgot that expected value can be negative even if the probabilities can't.

Comment: When you write \mathbb{P} rather than \operatorname{\mathbb{P}} or just \operatorname{P} or just \Pr, then you see $$ \begin{align} & y \mathbb P(Y=y) \\ \text{instead of }\quad & y \operatorname{\mathbb P}(Y=y) \end{align} $$ When \operatorname{} is used, then the spacing to the left and write depends on the context.